# Listview Item color change onactivityResult

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I have created a listview and on list Item click I am starting an activity. I have a text in listview row. I want to change color of that textview when activity that I am calling on onItemClick finished or say return results and resultcode is RESULT_OK.

Anyone please help

Thanks in advance.

here is my code :

```
HeadingListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.HeaderList);
adapter = new CustomHeadingAdapter(getApplicationContext(), HeadingList);
HeadingListView.setAdapter(adapter);
HeadingListView.setOnItemClickListener(this);
```

OnItemClickListener code is :

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    Intent intent;
    switch (position){
        case 0:
            intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Activity1.class);
            intent.putExtras(AllFilledData.get(0));
            startActivityForResult(intent, position);
            break;
        case 1:
            intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Activity2.class);
            intent.putExtras(AllFilledData.get(1));
            startActivityForResult(intent, position);
            break;
        case 2:
            intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Activity3.class);
            intent.putExtras(AllFilledData.get(position));
            startActivityForResult(intent, position);
            break;
```

Here is OnActivity Result :

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case 0 :
            if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){
                Bundle bundle = data.getExtras();
                AllFilledData.set(requestCode, bundle);
                //Here I want to change color of TextView of listitem at position 0
            }
            break;
        case 1:
            if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){
                Bundle bundle = data.getExtras();
                AllFilledData.set(requestCode, bundle);
                //Here I want to change color of TextView of listitem at position 1
            }
            break;
        case 2:
            if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){
                Bundle bundle = data.getExtras();
                AllFilledData.set(requestCode, bundle);
                //Here I want to change color of TextView of listitem at position 2
            }
            break;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hmm..
first add method in Customized adapter in your code.

```
View v = listview.getChildAt(int position);
```

//return it's view located position from top of listview. 
//not adapter items position.

//and toss view to adapter.

```
adapter.ChangeTextViewColor(v);


public void ChangeTextViewColor(View v){TextView txt = v.childAt(int position); // or findViewbyId(int id);
```

txt.setTextColor(Color.parse(String RGBcode)); // or other way.
}

if keep textview color use viewholder.
in adapter's method getView

```
if(items.get(position).colorchangeType == change) textview.setTextViewColor....
```

and some change in onactivityresult.

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
switch (requestCode) {
    case 0 :
        if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){
            Bundle bundle = data.getExtras();
            AllFilledData.set(requestCode, bundle);
            adapter.getItem(requestCode).colorchangeType = change;
            adapter.notifysetdatachange();
            //Here I want to change color of TextView of listitem at position 0
        }
        break;
```

my english bad............. i hope help.